# Re-ordering the strings data in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a random data in the form of strings, for example:

```
M342    
M533    
L653   
M_321  
N-267  
M533  
L763  
N-267 
Q345
```

I want to rearrange the data sequentially in an integer, like:

```
1       
2       
3       
4       
5      
2       
6       
5      
7
```

In the reordering, do not use arithmetic progression techniques. But it will automatically add `n + 1` if there is new data / characters. If there is the same data / character from before then the numbering follows the previous numbering.

Are there any techniques or methods to overcome this problem? Thanks.

Comment: Can you provide the expected outcome after sorting using your example?

Answer (score 1):

Keep track of the items you've seen using a fast lookup structure, and increment the counter if you find a new item.

```
cache = {}
counter = 1
def process(item):
    result = cache.get(item, counter)
    if result == counter:
        counter += 1
    return result
result = [process(x) for x in your_data]
```